# Surah Al-A'raf verse 7:179 - Are we not among those who refuse to understand?

Tags: quran, jahannam, reading-quran, surat-al-araf

As we might already know, very few muslims today learn Quran by it's meaning. Many of us only learn to recite it. When asked, very few of them could answer that they knew the meaning of the verses they read.

It makes me wonder. Do we actually misunderstood the word `اِقْرَأْ` (read) since a while?. It reminds me of the verse 2:170 from Al-Baqarah that kind of scolding us for following our forefathers even they knew nothing.

There area two types of reading. First, you recite the words even you don't understand it. Second, you may not read it loud but you examine and understand it in your heart. So I come to the question, which type of reading the word `اِقْرَأْ` actually means. Is it both?.

The more I read and try to understand the Quran, the more I realize that it doesn't talk about recitation or reading out loud by lips. It's about understanding it as the message from Allah.

Surah Al-A'raf verse 7:179.

> *Indeed, We have created for Jahannam many jinn and humans. They have hearts they do not understand with, eyes they do not see with, and ears they do not hear with. They are like cattle. In fact they are even less guided! Such people are entirely heedless.*

The verse talks about using our eyes, ears, and heart, to read, hear, and understand Allah's words, which mentioned in previous verses.

So my question is, are we not among those who refuse to read, hear, and understand Allah's words, choose to become more lost than a cattle, choose to become heedless, and choose to go to Jahannam?. If we are, that's terrifying and I don't want to become one.

Comment: Who's this "we" you speak of? As written, it sounds like you're worried _you personally_ might be wrong about something, and expect everyone else to be believing the same thing, which is all sorts of presumptuous.

Comment: @goldPseudo i think i've stated my question clearly. you need to actually read it not just the title. i don't know what else do i missing. let's talk more about the question not about me personally

Answer (score 0):

Those who recite the Quran without understanding should make an effort to understand or at least read a trustworthy translation in their native language.

Muslims who are reciting the Quran but aren't understanding the Arabic doesn't mean they're refusing the message and understanding of the Quran and Islam. For example, many Muslims don't actively read the Quran but follow it's rulings such as don't eat swine. Many Muslims have not memorized the exact Surah and ayah that prohibits swine in the Quran yet they still follow it. When/if they read the Arabic text of the Quran and don't understand it, doesn't mean they're not following Islam and don't know its rulings.

So Quran 7:179 is talking about the disbelievers by describing them as having eyes that do not perceive, ears that do not hear, and that they are like further astray than cattle.

[**Tafsir Al-Jalalayn - Quran 7:179**](https://archive.org/details/AlJalalainEng/page/n181/mode/1up)

> [7:179] **And We have indeed urged unto Hell many of the jinn and mankind, having hearts wherewith
> they do not understand,** the truth, **and having eyes wherewith they do not perceive,** the proofs of God’s
> power with a perception that entails reflection, **and having ears wherewith they do not hear,** the signs
> or the admonitions, in a way so as to reflect and take heed. **These, they are like cattle,** in their failure to
> understand, perceive or listen — **nay, rather they are further astray,** than cattle, because [at least] they
> [cattle] seek what is beneficial to them and stay away from what is harmful to them: these individuals,
> on the other hand, are proceeding towards the Fire, out of [sheer] obstinacy. **These — they are the heedless**.

To read more about this Ayah, check out this [Study Quran PDF](https://ia904603.us.archive.org/25/items/the-study-quran_202111/The%20Study%20Quran.pdf) (Page 1041)

Comment: if they follow without understand then it'll goes 17:36 doesn't it?. the verse even connected to 7:179

Comment: "Pursue not that whereof you have no knowledge" can mean that one
should not speak of things about which one does not have proper knowledge or
falsely claim to have knowledge about something that one does not in fact have.

"Truly hearing, and sight, and the heart—all of these will be called to account."  these three faculties will be called to account, meaning that one
will be held accountable for their proper or improper use (R, Ṭs).

Check out the Study Quran PDF link, page 1572 for a holistic, in-depth commentary on 17:36.

Comment: @stackunderflow You should read the tafsirs of these ayahs and any ayahs that you're confused about to understand what they mean and if they relate or not.

Comment: i doubt it's about speaking what we don't know. the word use there is قف means follow the practice. it's slightly different from تَبِعَ because تَبِعَ means follow the teaching or command

Comment: I copied some of the commentary but not all of it for 17:36 from the Study Quran PDF link. As I mentioned in my answer 7:179 is talking about how the disbelievers don't use their eyes, ears, and hearts to recognize the truth. 

The human faculties of hearing, and sight, and the heart are frequently
invoked in the Quran, as they are understood to be three means by which people
are guided to truth.
In 17:36, is a message to us all. Pursue not can also be rendered simply “Follow not,” indicating that one should not follow a path or a guide without knowing whether one will be led or misled;

Comment: Furthermore In 17:36, the hearing and the sight and the heart — each of these will be asked, of what a person did with them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer I got from somewhere.

The word `قَلْب` in the verse which usually translated as `heart` in Quran, actually means something we use to understand, which is known today as `brain`. It's normal that day to use heart as the symbol of decision making, as the output of the brain. The etymology of the word itself means `changing`. That means the verse is actually talking about understanding Allah's guidance using the brain. That bring us to the word `قْرَأْ` or `أَتْلُ`. Nowhere in Quran shows it's meaning as `reciting`. The meaning is always `reading + understanding`.

When Quran says we book a ticket to `destruction (jahannam)` by not using our brain to understand it, that means Quran is something we could and must use our brain to understand. We found it difficult to understand and to follow only because we refuse to try to understand it ourselves using our brain. Why?. It's because since childhood we were educated to not use our brain to understand religion. We were doctrined to let them with qualification to understand it for us. Isn't that opposite with what Quran says?.

The result is we don't understand God's words ourselves, we confidently believe what we don't even read and understand, we follow someone's teaching blindly, and in the end we become doubtful to fully follow the Quran. Why not?. We don't understand it and we learned from someone who don't understand it either. A lost cattle can still find it's way back home if not attacked by a beast. But Quran says we'll be worse than the lost cattle, which means as long as we don't understand Quran, we're done.

Let's see what Quran actually says about that.

Al-Ankabut 29:2-3.

> *Do people think they will be left to say "we believe" without being put to the test?. We certainly tested those before them. And in this way Allah will clearly distinguish between those who are truthful and those who are liars.*

Al-Isra' 17:36.

> *Do not follow what you have no knowledge of. Indeed, all will be called to account for their hearing, sight, and intellect.*